# I want to create a partition table month wise only 12 tables for multiple years

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, postgresql-9.5, table-partitioning

I am new to the partitioning of a table and I want to make a partition of the table by range type on the inserted_on column in this table the records are inserted around ~ 40000 daily

I have tried creating a partition table as:
CREATE TABLE My.table_name_fy2022_01 PARTITION OF My.table_name FOR VALUES FROM ('2022-01-01') TO ('2022-02-01');

But this way i will have to create 12 tables per year and that I don't want to do.

My question is:- how to create a partition table such as the no. of partition table be only 12 (months wise) and stores the data according to a specific month's partition.
For Example:-
partition table June
record of 2022-06-20 insert into June,
record of 2023-06-16 insert into June,
record of 2024-06-10 insert into June,
and So on

Comment: Please show sample input and expected outcome.

Comment: Upgrade to PostgreSQL v14 if you want to use partitioning.

Comment: What happens when you used the examples from the manual?

Answer (score 0):

PARTITION BY HASH should be used like:

```
PARTITION BY HASH(MONTH(use_time)) PARTITIONS 12;
```